# DateTimePicker Material UI set minDate 30 minutes from now

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I'm using Material UI `DateTimePicker` and am trying to set a minimum date to 60 minutes from now and can't figure out what's the right syntax to do it. The way I have it now doesn't work.
I tried using `minTime` instead as I saw that in one tutorial but that gave me a warning:

```
React does not recognize the `minTime` prop on a DOM element
```

Could someone tell me what's the right syntax to set the time to 60 minutes from now?

My `DateTimePicker`:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <DateTimePicker
              required={true}
              id="select-due-date-time"
              label="Due date"
              name="dueDateTime"
              disablePast
              error={materialDateTimeInputError}
              value={dueDateTime}
              onChange={handleDateChange}
              minDate={new Date().getMinutes + 60}
              minDateMessage={"Due date must be at least 60 minutes from now"}
              helperText="Please select the due date for your request"
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

I also tried something like this but it also didn't work `minDate={new Date(new Date().getMinutes + 60)}`

EDIT:
I tried using `minDate={new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60*60*1000)}` as someone suggested in the comment. Unfortunately, that didn't work. Is it even possible to set control `minTime`'s minutes? So far this attribute only worked for me for days.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I can confirm that `minDate` works only for days and not for hours/minutes/seconds.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-datetimepicker-forked-0ff93?file=/app.jsx) an example.

If you write in `minDate` something like:

```
<DateTimePicker
    value={this.state.date || Date.now()}
    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
    format="hh:mm DD.MM.YYYY"
    autoOk
    ampm={false}
    minDate={new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + 1)}
  />
```

gives you the same result as:

```
<DateTimePicker
    value={this.state.date || Date.now()}
    onChange={this.handleDateChange}
    format="hh:mm DD.MM.YYYY"
    autoOk
    ampm={false}
    minDate={new Date()}
  />
```

I tried mutiple times (also by using `moment`) but the result is the same.
A possible workaround could be verify the date in `onChange` event and display an error if date is less than one hour from now (poor but is the only way I found).

Answer (score 0):

Meterial Ui now support for **minDateTime** to validate minimum time with date.

Documentation - [meterial-ui DateTimePicker](https://mui.com/api/date-time-picker/)